# File format to save data in file and How to read this data - Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I'm kinda new bie to Spring MVC. While working on a project , there is use case where I need to fetch some data from file and populate it in jsp.

```
            public HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>  getFooterMoreLinks(){

            HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>> myArray = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>();
            HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> valueArr =   new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
            valueArr.put("heading",new ArrayList<String>() {{add("More Links");} } );
            valueArr.put("row1",new ArrayList<String>() {{add("About-us");add("http://www.example.com");} } );
            valueArr.put("row2",new ArrayList<String>() {{add("Investor Relation");add("http://www.example.com");} } ); //so on
    myArray.put("more_links", valueArr);

            HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> partnerSiteLinksArray    =   new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
            partnerSiteLinksArray.put("heading" ,new ArrayList<String>() {{add("Partner Heading");} } ); 
            partnerSiteLinksArray.put("row1" ,new ArrayList<String>() {{add("Support");add("http://www.example.com");} }  );
partnerSiteLinksArray.put("rowe" ,new ArrayList<String>() {{add("Daily Deails");add("http://www.example.com");} }  ); //so on

    myArray.put("partner_programs", partnerSiteLinksArray);

    }
```

And Populating the `myArray` in jsp. Everthing is working fine but I need to pick all these hard-coded value from file. Please help! Because .properties file doesnt support array like format.

Answer (score 1):

### Storing configuration in .properties file

Then you need to have your `.properties` file, which is standart java properties file with following format:

> foo.properties

```
some.property.key=42
someother.property.key=Username has to be at least 5 characters long
```

More about format and usage of .properties files can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties).

### Making your properties visible to spring

First you need to declare the bean which spring uses to access your property files.

```
<bean id="myProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>classpath*:foo.properties</value>
      <value>classpath*:bar.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Or when you are using Spring Java Configuration, you have to use

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/myco/app.properties")
```

### Using values in your spring beans

Then you cann access you property file through property object in your java classes.

```
@Component
class MyClass {
  @Resource(name="foo")
  private Properties fooProperties;

  @Resource(name="bar")
  private Properties barProperties;

  //Use your properties as neccessary
}
```

Alternatively, you can inject concrete values from your property files directly. This is simpler when you have smaller amount of values. In @Value annotation you use property name (key) to inject its value

```
@Value("${some.property.key}")
private String value;
```

Comment: cool. But how to store these value in file ? format ?(I want to pre-store these values in files and directly fetch these from files)

Comment: Updated my answer with information about property files.